# JavaScript - Select radio button if any checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, radio-button

I'm trying to write JavaScript code where a radio button should be populated if a checkbox is checked.

Following is the HTML code:

```
<form>
   <h3>Radio Buttons</h3>
   <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="radio1"> Radio 1
   <br>
   <input type="radio" name="radio2" id="radio2">Radio 2
   <br>
   <br>

   <h3>Checkbox Groups</h3>

   <h4><u>Group 1</u></h4>
   <p align="center"><u>PD</u></p>
   <ul>
      <li>
         <input id="pdcb" type="checkbox" name="G1PD1" onclick="validate()">G1 PD1</li>
      <li>
         <input id="pdcb" type="checkbox" name="G1PD2" onclick="validate()">G1 PD2</li>
   </ul>
   <p align="center"><u>ID</u></p>
   <ul>
      <li>
         <input id="idcb" type="checkbox" name="G1ID1" onclick="validate()">G1 ID1</li>
      <li>
         <input id="idcb" type="checkbox" name="G1ID2" onclick="validate()">G1 ID2</li>
   </ul>

   <h4><u>Group 2</u></h4>
   <p align="center"><u>PD</u></p>
   <ul>
      <li>
         <input id="pdcb" type="checkbox" name="G2PD1" onclick="validate()">G2 PD1</li>
      <li>
         <input id="pdcb" type="checkbox" name="G2PD2" onclick="validate()">G2 PD2</li>
   </ul>
   <p align="center"><u>ID</u></p>
   <ul>
      <li>
         <input id="idcb" type="checkbox" name="G2ID1" onclick="validate()">G2 ID1</li>
      <li>
         <input id="idcb" type="checkbox" name="G2ID2" onclick="validate()">G2 ID2</li>
   </ul>
</form>
```

So here's what I want the JavaScript to do: If any of the `PD` checkboxes are selected, then the radio button `Radio 1` should get selected. If none of the `PD` checkboxes are selected, then the radio button `Radio 2` should get selected. Similarly, if none of the checkboxes are selected, then NONE of the radio buttons should get selected.

So far, I've written the following JS code:

```
function validate()
{
    if(document.getElementById("pdcb").checked) //if pdcb checkbox(es) is/are checked
  { 
    document.getElementById("radio1").checked = true;
    document.getElementById("radio2").checked = false;
  }  
  else if (!document.getElementById("pdcb").checked) //if none of the pdcb checkbox(es) is/are checked
  { 
    document.getElementById("radio1").checked = false;
    document.getElementById("radio2").checked = true;
  }
  else //if no checkbox is checked, then don't populate any radio button
  {
    document.getElementById("radio1").checked = false;
    document.getElementById("radio2").checked = false;
  }

}
```

PS: I need the code to be in pure JavaScript. I can't use jQuery.

### Edit

I apologize for getting my requirements wrong. But here's the correct requirement. If any of the `PD` checkboxes are selected, then the radio button `Radio 1` should get selected. If none of the `PD` checkboxes are selected, then the radio button `Radio 2` should get selected. Similarly, if none of the checkboxes are selected, then NONE of the radio buttons should get selected.

Comment: @8protons I'm trying to get the URL for the JSFiddle. But it doesn't seem to be working. It is going to the previous JSFiddle before making the changes.

Comment: No worries; I made one for ya in my answer.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I want to first point out that if you were testing this in a JSFiddle, the **LOAD TYPE** needs to be set to "No Wrap-in " for your inline `onclick` events to work.

Now, to your code. Document elements can either be tied to a `class` or `ID`. Classes are for when you're using elements that share the same functionality, styling, etc.; ID's are for unique elements and *unique elements only*. For example, in your JavaScript, when you try to test for checked `pdcb` elements with

`document.getElementById("pdcb").checked`

JavaScript simply grabs **the first** element on the page with the ID of `pdcb`. You have four elements with this ID name; this means that the last three `pdcb` elements are ignored and never evaluated.

Instead, let's utilize

```
document.getElementsByClassName("pdcb")
```

Note the plural form of the word *'Element'*. What this does is it returns an array of **all** elements with the class name of `pdcb`. We'll get to the fact that we're dealing with an array in a few minutes. First, let's change most of your HTML ID's to classes.

```
<ul>
   <li>
      <input class="pdcb" type="checkbox" name="G1PD1" onclick="validate()">G1 PD1</li>
   <li>
      <input class="pdcb" type="checkbox" name="G1PD2" onclick="validate()">G1 PD2</li>
</ul>
```

You're going to want to do this for all of your `pdcb` and `idcb` elements. Feel free to preserve `radio1` and `radio2` as `ID`'s because they're unique elements, not reused like `pdcb` and `idcb` are.

---

Now we can address the JavaScript; you're HTML is fine from here assuming you've made the changes necessary from above. Since we changed things from ID's to classes, expressions like the following simply won't do.

`document.getElementById("pdcb")`

Recall the solution that I wrote earlier:

`document.getElementsByClassName("pdcb")`

Also recall that I said that this will return an array of elements; in your case, four `pdcb` elements.

One option that you have at your disposal for tackling this problem is that you can iterate through the array of elements returned by `document.getElementsByClassName("pdcb")` to evaluate whether any `pdcb` class has been checked. It'll look something like this:

```
var pdcbClass = document.getElementsByClassName("pdcb");

    //for each pdcb class on our HTML document
    for (var i = 0; i < pdcbClass.length; i++) {
       if (pdcbClass[i].checked == true) {
          //the next two lines are straight from your JavaScript code
          document.getElementById("radio1").checked = true;
          document.getElementById("radio2").checked = false;
        }
    }
```

As you can imagine, we can use the exact same idea for the `idcb` class elements on your page. By the time we're done, we should have something like what you see below.

```
function validate()
{
  var pdcbClass = document.getElementsByClassName("pdcb");
  var idcbClass = document.getElementsByClassName("idcb");
  console.log(this);
    for (var i = 0; i < pdcbClass.length; i++) {
    if (pdcbClass[i].checked == true) {
       document.getElementById("radio1").checked = true;
         document.getElementById("radio2").checked = false;
    }
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < idcbClass.length; i++) {
    if (idcbClass[i].checked == true) {
      document.getElementById("radio1").checked = false;
      document.getElementById("radio2").checked = true;
    }
  }
}
```

But there's a problem! No matter what check box fires off this `validate()` function, no check box is ever turned off. That means if we check a box with the  `pdcb` class and then check a box with the `idcb` class, the `pdcb` box still stays checked; we never said to uncheck it. What this means is that even though it was an `idcb` click that triggered `validate()`, **all of the code in the function gets executed**. Either you have to have the user manually uncheck the previous box before checking a new one, or you need to write some code that does this same thing. Specifically, when a new check box is checked, **you need to clear the previous box(es) of their `checked` property**.

That is an entirely different problem and merits a different question. Also consider that this isn't the only way to write this event/functionality, but you're making good progress.

Here's essentially the code you need to keep on going.

https://jsfiddle.net/a4k9xggu/

Comment: Thanks a ton for answering! I tried your JSFiddle code. But, it somehow doesn't work the `PDCB` checkboxes in Group 2. Do I have to create a new variable for that?

Comment: @user2201650 lol I'm sorry, I didn't realize you had used the same ID name for multiple things. Let me edit and update.

Comment: @user2201650 There's actually a lot that I want to write out and explain to you because there's a lot here that's just going to trip you up later and I'd like to avoid that. I'll probably update this in about an 90 minutes because there really is a lot to go over and I need to run an errand real quick.

Comment: @user2201650 To give you a taste of what's to come, when you write `document.getElementById("pdcb")`, that only grabs the FIRST element of  pdcb on the page; all the others get ignored. See how this is starting to go down a scary road? No worries, though, I have a fully running fix but I won't post until I finish writing up the explanation.

Comment: Thanks a ton for your explanation! You made it so much clear to me. One last thing, how do I uncheck the radio buttons if none of the checkboxes are checked?

Comment: @user2201650 As I wrote in the answer, "That is an entirely different problem and merits a different question." :] It's useful to keep Stack Overflow to one question and one answer so that way others who have the same issue you have here don't get lost in a web of irrelevant information. So ask that in a separate question and make sure to upvote and accept answers that have helped you!

Comment: Thanks for the info! :) But, I already asked that question in my original question. Do you still want me to ask it in a separate question?

Comment: @user2201650 I'll see what I can do later today once I'm done with some errands :]

Comment: @user2201650 Okay ready to work on it. Can you specify in your question if only one radio button can be selected at a time? As in, is there a limit to the combination of check boxes and/or what check boxes exist in what group?

Comment: Only one radio button can be selected at a time. If none of the checkboxes are selected, then none of the radio buttons should get populated. There's no limit on the number of checkboxes. Group 1 has 8 checkboxes in total. Group 2 has like 10 checkboxes in total.

Comment: @user2201650 Okay, so if only one radio button can be checked at a time, then any checked check boxes must either be all pdcb or all idcb but they cannot be a combination of the two, correct?

Comment: Hey, I got my requirements wrong. I edited my question above with the correct requirements. Could you please take a look at it?